# How to install Cairo 1.8.10

Tags: package-management, graphics, cairo

The package `libcairo2-dev` is the latest version of the Cairo graphics library (1.10.2). Is there any way I can install version 1.8.10?

I'm running 11.10, but would be interested in a general solution if possible.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to install the older version?  Installing the older version system wide is probably not a possibility (some programs may depend on features of the newer release), but if you have a narrower requirement for the older version then a solution might be possible.

Comment: I personally know very little about Cairo, but I have written a program that links to a library that in turn uses Cairo to generate graphics. I did most of the original development on my Mac, for which Cairo installation was only available through something like Fink (which only has v1.8.10)...

Comment: ...The program also uses OpenMP, and one of the parallelized for loops includes calls to the Cairo library functions. The program works on Ubuntu when I run it on a single processor, and it works on Mac for any number of processors. But when I run it on Ubuntu with multiple processors, I get aborts, segfaults, glibcs, etc.

Comment: I understand that downgrading to v1.8.10 isn't something you would want for a long term solution, and if you could isolate the installation it may even be better. I have already distributed the software and I simply want to have a temporary stop-gap until I can figure out what's *really* wrong with my program.

Comment: For reference, the version numbers for Cairo go 1.8 -> 1.9 -> 1.10, so the version included with Ubuntu should be able to do everything the version you used on MacOS did.  If you're only accessing Cairo through a third party library you aren't modifying, you shouldn't have to worry about accidentally using new features and breaking compatibility with your old development environment either.  If you have run into a problem with the new version, could you explain what it is?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Since I am unfamiliar with Cairo itself, I don't know whether the problem is with Cairo or OpenMP or (likely) my implementation. Either way, getting into these details would almost certainly be off-topic for this site. I'll probably start a thread on SO for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to test out an old version of Cairo, you can build it in a temporary prefix in your home directory.

First of all, make sure you've got Cairo's build dependencies installed.  You can do this with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep cairo
```

Now download and unpack the old version of Cairo:

```
wget http://cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.8.10.tar.gz
tar xzf cairo-1.8.10.tar.gz
cd cairo-1.8.10
```

Now you want to build Cairo into a temporary prefix.  I've used `~/prefix` for this on a few occasions, but you can use any directory.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/prefix
make
make install
```

Now you need to make your own software use this version of Cairo.  If the software uses `pkg-config` to locate its dependencies, it should only be necessary to set the following environment variable:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/prefix/lib/pkgconfig
```

If it isn't using `pkg-config`, you might need to adjust `CFLAGS` to include `-I$HOME/prefix/include` and `LDFLAGS` to include `-L$HOME/prefix/lib`.

Finally, to run your program using the custom version of Cairo you will need to configure the dynamic linker so it looks for shared libraries in your temporary prefix:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/prefix/lib
```

Once that is set, you can verify that your program is linking against your copy of Cairo using `ldd`.  If that looks okay, you're all done.

**Cleaning Up**

Once you're done with this temporary install, cleaning up is pretty easy.  Just reset the environment variables and remove the temporary install prefix:

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH
rm -rf $HOME/prefix
```

You may need to reconfigure/rebuild your program after doing this to make it use the system Cairo again.

Comment: Excellent and clear instructions, with a clean install and uninstall process. Thanks!

Comment: How to remove default include paths from $HOME so that it will not use default cairo files