# Compiling C++ in Ubuntu ( psa - Point Set Analysis)

Tags: compiling, c++, cairo

I'm new in Ubuntu and trying to compile a C++ code on it. The code uses 2 dependencies (Cairographics and FFTW3). I have installed both of them using `./configure`, `make` and  `make install` in directory `$HOME/prefix/` (following the instruction given here [How to install Cairo 1.8.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108662/how-to-install-cairo-1-8-10) )

Now I have in this directory 4 folders, namely `bin`, `include`, `lib` and `share`

The make file of the code requires specifying the dependencies' directory. Like that

```
INC := -I$HOME/prefic/include
LIB := -L$HOME/prefic/lib
```

When I compile the code, I set the environment variables as

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/prefic/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/prefic/lib
```

and then use make. Linker gives "*undefined reference to*" functions from inside Cairo or FFTW

the make file I use

```
###################### user-configuration section #######################
INC := -I/opt/local/include
LIB := -L/opt/local/lib

# 32 bit
#MARCH := -m32

# 64 bit
MARCH := -m64
#########################################################################

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -fopenmp
OPTFLAGS := -O3 $(MARCH) 

LIB += -lfftw3 -lm -lcairo

CXXFILES := main.cpp fileio.cpp measurements.cpp spectralanalysis.cpp
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(CXXFILES))
TARGET := psa

.PHONY: all clean cleanall rebuild

 all: $(TARGET)

  $(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(LIB) $(OBJS)

 %.o : %.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ -c $<

 clean:
    rm -rf *.o

  cleanall:     clean
    rm -rf $(TARGET)

 rebuild:
     $(MAKE) cleanall
     $(MAKE) all
```

I think I don't link the code with the dependencies correctly. Could someone help please.

The psa code I'm trying to compile is here http://code.google.com/p/psa/downloads/list

Comment: use gnu c++ complier

Comment: Do you know about CodeBlocks? or Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to move the libraries to the end of the command line (in your `Makefile`: place `$(LIB)` after `$(OBJS)`). The linker flag `--as-needed` is activated by default [since Ubuntu 11.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ToolchainTransition). This makes the linker sensitive to the ordering of libraries on the command-line.

By the way: I don't know if you already know that, but you don't need to install Cairo and FFTW3 from source.

You can install the dependencies with the package management system:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libfftw3-dev
```

Then you have to change the following two lines in the `Makefile`:

```
INC := -I/usr/include
LIB := -L/usr/lib
```